# SharePoint Javascript Internet 11 issue

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

Code works in Edge and Chrome but does not display in Internet Explorer 11.   Not displaying row formatting in 11.

Windows 8 build
SharePoint 2013 On Premise
Explorer 11

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    (function () {

    var ctxContext = {};
    ctxContext.Templates = {};
    ctxContext.OnPostRender = formatOnPostRender;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxContext);

    }) ();

  function formatOnPostRender(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    var now = new Date().toDateString();
    var today = new Date(now);
    //console.log("Today: " + today);

    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var listDate = ConvertSPListDate(rows[i]       ["Start_x0020_Date"].toString());
        //console.log("SPListItem " + i + ": " + listDate);     

        if (listDate <= today)
        {
            var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
            tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ffcccc";

        }else{
             var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
             var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
             tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ffebcc";
        }
    }
  }

   function ConvertSPListDate(_date){

    var date = new Date();

    if(_date != null)
    {
        var day = _date.substr(0,2);
        var month = _date.substr(3,2);
        var year = _date.substr(6,4);
        var time = " 00:00:00";
        var newdate = year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day + time;

        date = new Date(newdate);
    }

    return date;
   }
```

Thanking you in advance.

M.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to IE implementation of `Date`. Parsing using hypens (`-`) instead of slashes (`/`) works in Web-Kit browsers but not on IE. Try changing your `ConvertSPListDate` method to following:

```
function ConvertSPListDate(_date) {
  var date = new Date();

  if (_date != null) {
    var day = _date.substr(0, 2);
    var month = _date.substr(3, 2);
    var year = _date.substr(6, 4);
    var time = " 00:00:00";
    var newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + time;

    date = new Date(newdate);
  }

  return date;
}
```

For the IE handling of input date-time formats you can check http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html it hasn't really been changed till Edge.